# New compiler issues of the same project but in different workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Android project completely fine, then I created a separate workspace and imported that project in it. In this new workspace Eclipse shows me several similar issues and advice to remove the @Override annotations for some methods like:

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   }
  });
```

I checked project's properties, JREs and Android APIs - everything is similar. 
I tried to clean the project, this didn't help.

Eclipse's error description:

```
 The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a
 superclass method  Ovals.java  /FlyingOvals/src/com/g/g    line 38 Java Problem
```

Why can it be and where should I look to fix these issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Java compliance level in the new workspace. In Java 5, @Override was not allowed when implementing methods from an interface. In Java 6, this was allowed. Eclipse will flag a code style warning for this case if it is applicable. You can either set Java compliance level to Java 5 (ideally in the project, so that the settings persist) or you can selectively disable this warning all together for the project.

See Project Properties -> Java Compiler

See Project Properties -> Java Compiler -> Errors Warnings.

I should add that the use of @Override annotation is generally recommended as it will alert you when a base class changes. Consider class Foo with method abc() and a derived class Bar that overrides that method. If you tag abc() method in Bar with @Override, when someone renames abc() method in Foo, you will get alerted as Bar.abc() is no longer overriding anything as it is declaring.

Comment: That is why I love stackoverflow so much! Thanks a lot!